# Remove character from img src

Tags: jquery, edit, src

I want to edit my img src and so far i found this:

```
$('.foo').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '-thumb$&');
});
```

But this adds -thumb so i thought remove would do the trick but it doesn't.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to change the img src?  What exactly do you want to change from what to what?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.foo').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace("-thumb", "");
});
```

Edit:

Will this work?

```
$('.foo').attr('src', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace("%7Bthumdir_3%7D", "images/thumbs/");
});
```

or does the pattern of the string which is "%7Bthumdir_3%7D" in your example vary?

Comment: Hi Jonas that works, but i found out that it doesn't delete the special characters. Like: %7Bthumbdir_3%7D to "nothing"

Comment: @Eddyfever could you give an example of the desired src before and after?

Comment: http://www.mysite.nl/%7Bthumdir_3%7Dlogo.png to http://www.mysite.nl/images/thumbs/logo.png

Comment: @Eddyfever looks like you're after [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i understand what you mean, but i have no clue how to solve that :D

Comment: @Eddyfever well, `mysite.nl/%7Bthumdir_3%7Dlogo.png` becomes `mysite.nl/{thumdir_3}logo.png` - what is this "{thumdir_3}"? How you expect to replace it with "images/thumbs"?

Comment: My first thought was jquery text replace %7Bthumdir_3%7D for images/thumbs/ but it isn't that easy as i thought. But the code from @JonasH comes close.